# Extract email string from string in bash

Tags: string, bash

I have a variable: `$change`.

I have tried to extract email from it (find the string between "by" and "@"):

```
change="Change 1234 on 2016/08/31 by name@company.com 'cdex abcd'"
email=$(echo $change|sed -e 's/\by\(.*\)@/\1/')
```

It did not work.

Comment: what is your expected output, for ex: `name` or `name@company.com` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an escape character before `b`, which makes it `\b`. And this is a word boundary, so something you don't want here.

See the difference:

```
$ echo "$change" | sed -e 's/\by\(.*\)@/\1/'
#                            ^
Change 1234 on 2016/08/31 by name@company.com 'cdex abcd'
$ echo "$change" | sed -e 's/by\(.*\)@/\1/'
#                            ^
Change 1234 on 2016/08/31  namecompany.com 'cdex abcd'
#                        ^
#                        by is not here any more
```

But if you want to get the name, just use `.*` to match everything up to `by`:

```
$ echo "$change" | sed -e 's/.*by\(.*\)@/\1/'
 namecompany.com 'cdex abcd'
```

Finally, if what you want is just the data between `by` (note the trailing space) and `@`, use either of these (with `-r` you don't have to escape the captured groups):

```
sed -e 's/.*by \(.*\)@.*/\1/'
sed -r 's/.*by (.*)@.*/\1/'
```

With your input:

```
$ sed -e 's/.*by \(.*\)@.*/\1/' <<< "Change 1234 on 2016/08/31 by name@company.com 'cdex abcd'"
name
```

Comment: What if $change included a few emails? What should I change to get all names separated with comma for example?

Comment: @OkyDokyman, try `echo "$change" | perl -ne '(@a)=/(\w+)@/g; print join(",",@a)'`

Comment: or just `echo "$change" | perl -ne 'print join(",",/(\w+)@/g)'`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works!

Answer (score 2):

Using `grep -oP` you can use match reset `\K`:

```
grep -oP ' by \K[^@]*' <<< "$change"
name
```

or using lookbehind:

```
grep -oP '(?<= by )[^@]*' <<< "$change"
name
```

Comment: Nice! I was about to post something related but you beat me to it, so I stick to the `sed` version :)

Comment: Your sed version is what OP needs probably, I just provided an alternate way.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to resort sed, awk, grep, etc. use regular expression matching:

```
[[ $change =~ by\ ([^@]*)@ ]] && email=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

From the man page

> An additional binary operator, =~, is available, with  the  same
>       precedence  as  ==  and  !=.  When it is used, the string to the
>       right of the operator is considered an extended regular  expres-
>       sion and matched accordingly (as in regex(3)).  The return value
>       is 0 if the string matches the pattern, and 1 otherwise.  If the
>       regular  expression  is syntactically incorrect, the conditional
>       expression's return value is 2.  If the shell option nocasematch
>       is enabled, the match is performed without regard to the case of
>       alphabetic characters.  Any part of the pattern may be quoted to
>       force  the  quoted  portion  to be matched as a string.  Bracket
>       expressions in regular expressions must  be  treated  carefully,
>       since  normal  quoting  characters  lose  their meanings between
>       brackets.  If the pattern is stored in a shell variable, quoting
>       the  variable  expansion forces the entire pattern to be matched
>       as a string.  Substrings matched by parenthesized subexpressions
>       within  the  regular  expression are saved in the array variable
>       BASH_REMATCH.  The element of BASH_REMATCH with index 0  is  the
>       portion  of  the  string matching the entire regular expression.
>       The element of BASH_REMATCH with index n is the portion  of  the
>       string matching the nth parenthesized subexpression.

It might be surprising, that the pattern is written without surrounding quotes, which is why it is probably a good idea to use a variable for the pattern instead:

```
regex='by ([^@]*)@'
[[ $change =~ $regex ]] && email=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/.* by ([^@]+).*/\1/' <<<"$change"
```

With `awk`:

```
awk -F@ '{sub(".* ", "", $1); print $1}' <<<"$change"
```

**Example:**

```
$ sed -E 's/.* by ([^@]+).*/\1/' <<<"Change 1234 on 2016/08/31 by name@company.com 'cdex abcd'"
name

$ awk -F@ '{sub(".* ", "", $1); print $1}' <<<"Change 1234 on 2016/08/31 by name@company.com 'cdex abcd'"
name
```

Answer (score 1):

awk version, this will use awk's inbuilt split function to split 6th field using "@" as delimiter and store it in an array named a.  Print it for printing first value of array a.

```
echo $change |awk  '{ split($6,a,"@"); print a[1]}' 
name
```

In case you need complete email address then :

```
 echo $change |awk '{print $6}'
 name@company.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution with [Parameter Expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion)

First, a temporary variable that deletes string upto `by` and a space

```
$ change="Change 1234 on 2016/08/31 by name@company.com 'cdex abcd'"
$ tmp="${change#*by }"
$ echo "$tmp"
name@company.com 'cdex abcd'
```

Then, extract either the string before `@`

```
$ email="${tmp%@*}"
$ echo "$email"
name
```

Or, extract complete email address

```
$ email="${tmp%% *}"
$ echo "$email"
name@company.com
```

**Edit:**

To extract multiple strings separated by comma:

```
$ change="Change 1234 on 2016/08/31 by name@company.com 'cdex abcd'"
$ email=$(echo "$change" | perl -ne 'print join(",",/(\S+)@/g)')
$ echo "$email"
name

$ change="by name@company.com asd abcd@xyz.net 123 tom@xyz asdf"
$ email=$(echo "$change" | perl -ne 'print join(",",/(\S+)@/g)')
$ echo "$email"
name,abcd,tom
```